# Efficient way of using a setter

Tags: java, android

```
public class GraphFrame extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    Integer hoodSelector = 27;
    ArrayList<HoodData> hoodDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> hoodList = new ArrayList<>();

    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        // Showing selected spinner item
        if (item.equals(hoodList.get(0))) {
            setHoodId(27);
            //refreshFragment();
        } else if (item.equals(hoodList.get(1))) {
            setHoodId(28);
            refreshFragment();
        } else if (item.equals(hoodList.get(2))) {
            setHoodId(29);
            refreshFragment();
        } else if (item.equals(hoodList.get(3))) {
   ...
        else if (item.equals(hoodList.get(65))) {
            setHoodId(92);
            refreshFragment();
        }
    }
...
```

I've wrote this code, and it's working but as you can see it's a bit messy because I define around the 67 times the same code.

What is would like to know is how can I do this more efficiently so I can scale this code and add in the future more "hoods" without adding them into the code.

Comment: I'm not sure the logic behind your code but looks like there is a mistake somewhere if you need to do this. Looks like more related to identify a type of fragment (instanceof someclass) and implement some method proper from that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
for(int i = 0; i < hoodList.size(); i++) {
  if (item.equals(hoodList.get(i))) {
        setHoodId(i+27); // or + hoodList.size() ?!
```

Of course, that might need some fine tuning (to not get "one off" in the end for example); but the main point is: that is what for-loops were invented for.

Besides, the real take-away here: Android "alone" is challenging. You should have **good** knowledge on Java before working on Android topics.  Trying to learn Java *while* learning Android is not very efficient. I would rather recommend you to work through the Oracle [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) first.

Comment: Thanks, I think I wrote to much code the past few days I should've known this

Comment: If the index in the list is all you need you can also use the [indexOf(item)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) method.